# Can an interrupting settlement allow opponents to move previously unmovable ships?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

Take a look at the following setup:

[image: Interrupting settlement.]

Given this board state, can blue move any of his ships? He was previously unable to, then white built the circled settlement, breaking blue's trade route.

The rules in seafarers say that a ship can be moved only if it doesn't connect two cities and it is not in the middle of a line of ships. Since a settlement interrupts a longest road, does it also count as breaking the above sea route into two disjoint lines of ships?

(NB Blue's settlement on the right was an original, the blue settlement on the left was placed after being reached with the shown sea route.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you may not move it, your ship is not open. From the [official site](http://www.catan.com/faq/23-seafarers/1000-ships-when-is-a-ship-open.html).

> A ship is “open” when it is located at the end of a ship route. As soon as a ship route connects two settlements, the ship route is considered as closed. A ship in a closed ship route can not be moved. This rule also applies if another player builds a settlement on the intersection of your closed ship route. In this case, the continuous road is considered as interrupted in terms of being counted towards the Longest Road; however, the two settlements of the ship route are still connected, meaning that the ship route remains closed.